# Rendering a region after rows

Tags: views

Having code issue.

I am rendering a the regions[ad_spot] = 'Ad Spot' so that it shows up after the first row.

For some reason it is not showing the region even tho I have put a block in there. So far I have not had an issue with my other regions I have made.

http://dev-honey-in-the-wild.pantheon.io/

Code is here: https://codeshare.io/bHx5N

Am I doing this correctly?

thanks!﻿

Answer (score 1):

I'm absolutely against to add code in templates...

but your problem is here:

```
<?php if ($row_id == 0): ?>
  <?php print render($page['ad_spot']); ?>
```

I think this is always FALSE.

Comment: How else can I do it if adding code into templates is bad.